# Calicoctl rejecting certificate on fresh k3s install

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, calico, k3s

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu, a fresh install of k3s, and a fresh download of calicoctl. I have installed it the following way.

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE="644"\
        INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--flannel-backend=none --cluster-cidr=192.168.0.0/16\
        --disable-network-policy --disable=traefik" sh -

kubectl create -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/tigera-operator.yaml
kubectl create -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/custom-resources.yaml

curl -o calicoctl -O -L  "https://github.com/projectcalico/calicoctl/releases/download/v3.20.2/calicoctl"
```

When I run kubectl, everything works fine. When I run calicoctl, I get certificate errors.

```
# calicoctl apply -f V000_000-host-policy.yaml 
Unable to get Cluster Information to verify version mismatch: Get "https://127.0.0.1:6443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Use --allow-version-mismatch to override.
```

I have copied `request-header-ca.crt`, `client-ca.crt` and `server-ca.crt` certificates from `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/tls` to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and applied them with `update-ca-certificates`. I can confirm the certs are listed in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

Additionally my `~/.kube/config` file has the following contents (I do regular reinstalls, none of this is confidential I should hope - correct me if I'm wrong)

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0t...LS0K
    server: https://127.0.0.1:6443
  name: default
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default
    user: default
  name: default
current-context: default
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0t...LS0K
    client-key-data: LS0t...LQo=
```

And I have the following configuration in `/etc/cni/net.d/calico-kubeconfig`

```
# Kubeconfig file for Calico CNI plugin. Installed by calico/node.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: local
  cluster:
    server: https://10.43.0.1:443
    certificate-authority-data: "LS0t...tLS0K"
users:
- name: calico
  user:
    token: eyJhb...tk4Q
contexts:
- name: calico-context
  context:
    cluster: local
    user: calico
current-context: calico-context
```

I have changed the address in calico-kubeconfig from `10.43.0.1:443` to `127.0.0.1:6443` but that made no difference.

Does anyone know how to work around this? Is the certificate error I am seeing a consequence of CA or tokens? Curl to the same address also complains about CA so it makes me think this is not token related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar setup (except `k3s` running inside an unprivileged Ubuntu LXD container) with the `k3s.service` started using:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/k3s \
    server --snapshotter=native \
    --kubelet-arg=feature-gates=KubeletInUserNamespace=true \
    --kube-controller-manager-arg=feature-gates=KubeletInUserNamespace=true \
    --kube-apiserver-arg=feature-gates=KubeletInUserNamespace=true,RemoveSelfLink=false \
    --disable=servicelb --disable=traefik --flannel-backend=none --disable-network-policy \
    --cluster-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --cluster-init
```

I didn't need to copy any certificates - it was enough to just:

`ln -s /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml ~/.kube/config`

- Thanks to the [first answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1079917/246407) for the hint.
- This is also indicated in the [k3s multi-node install](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/k3s/multi-node-install) now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By setting calicoctl log level to debug (ex. `calicoctl -l debug get nodes`) I discovered what was happening.

By default calicoctl reads `/etc/calico/calicoctl.cfg`. This file won't exist if you installed calicoctl the way I have. So the client falls back to using `~/.kube/config`. Which contains some information, but not all information.

As part of the debug log information, the loaded configuration is also displayed. I was able to deduce that the config properties were slightly different to those in [the documentation](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/clis/calicoctl/configure/kdd).

I created the following `/etc/calico/calicoctl.cfg` file (yaml format)

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: CalicoAPIConfig
metadata:
spec:
  datastoreType: "kubernetes"
  kubeconfig: "/home/user/.kube/config"
  K8sAPIToken: "eyJh...xQHA"
  K8sCAFile: "/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/tls/server-ca.crt"
```

Where the `K8sAPIToken` I took from `/etc/cni/net.d/calico-kubeconfig`. It should be the same token as the one from the question, I am unsure why it changed (refresh?). Either way, the above method solves the problem (at least temporarily).